# Apply jquery effect for divs of the same name property

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, plugins, effects

I'm having trouble in finding a way of applying an efect to a jquery plugin I'm making, I already have it working, but that's not the way I really wanted so I need a some guidance

The Jquery plug-in separate an image into small squares that are divs so I can apply a fade in effect starting from the corner, now every div has the same CSS class, but different names, their names are given according to the order in which the divs have to apear... the problem is that I dont now how to make all divs with name 3 for example fade in at the same time.. here is the code

THE HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="separar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <title>AEMB Portales Web</title>        
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="contenedor" style="width:800px; height:508px; position:relative; margin:0 auto;">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/fma.jpg"  /></a>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#contenedor").separar(4);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JQUERY PLUGIN

```
(function($){

$.fn.separar =  function(cantidad){
    var contenedor = $(this);
    var slides = $(this).children();
    var altoTotal = contenedor.height();
    var lastId = 0;


    separarslides(contenedor,slides[0]);
    aparecer();

    function separarslides(slider, hijo) {
        var imagen = hijo.children[0];
        $(hijo).hide();

                var anchoSlide = Math.round(slider.width()/cantidad);
                var altoSlide = Math.round(slider.height()/cantidad);
                var id = 0;
                var idFila = 1;

                for(var j = 0; j < altoTotal; j+=altoSlide){    
                    id = idFila;
                    for(var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++){                  
                        slider.append(
                            $('<div class="slice'+id+'" style="position:absolute;" name="'+id+'"><img src="'+ $(imagen).attr('src') +'" style="position:absolute; width:'+ slider.width() +'px; height:'+slider.height()+'px; display:block !important; top:'+ j*-1 +'px;; left:'+ i * anchoSlide*-1 +'px;" /></div>').css({ 
                                left:(anchoSlide*i)+'px',
                                top:j+'px',                         
                                width:anchoSlide+'px',
                                height:altoSlide+'px',
                                opacity:'0',
                                overflow:'hidden'
                            })
                        );                      
                        lastId = id;
                        id++;                       
                        if(i==3)
                           idFila++;                       
                    }                   
                }
        //slider.append($(alert(lastId)));  //Para ver el numero final que tiene lastId
    } 


    function aparecer(){

            var slices = $('.slice', contenedor);
            var time = 500;

            for(i=1;i<=lastId;i++){
               $(".slice"+i).fadeTo(time,1);
               time+=650;
            }
    }  
  }  
})(jQuery);
```

the last function in the javascript is in charge of appearing the divs, but in that case the divs have different classes, how can i make it by the name of the divs?

Comment: $('div[name="3"]') i think would work

Comment: :D it workss!! really works! thanks Jeff thanks!.. such a simple solution thanks for your time :), didn't know name can be retreive like that thanks again

Comment: I' add that as an answer than. Glad it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a selector that works for your case :

```
$('div[name="3"]')
```

Comment: While this might work for the OP, I want to repeat my warning from above:  The `name` attribute SHOULD NOT be used on a div.

Comment: Explaining WHY you shouldn't might be more helpful.

Comment: Comments on @Steve's answer explain his comment.

Comment: Missed that comment, or maybe it was just posted after this answer, but it makes sense. Didn't realize it was removed in HTML5

Comment: I did post it after your answer. Couldn't find the correct link in time, so I just posted what I knew with proof to follow later. :) Just FYI, it wasn't removed in HTML5, it was never in any HTML spec.

Comment: OTOH, I think HTML4 allowed for `name` on an `a` tag, but it was removed in HTML5's spec. That little detail bit my team at work recently... Just goes to show how people are still getting used to HTML5's details.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea they removed the `name` attribute from `a` tags... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First off, I am pretty sure you shouldn't use the `name` attribute on a `<div>` element.

So why don't you just use the classname as it uses the same id as your name attribute?

```
$('.slice3')
```

EDIT:  Here is an example of how I would structure it:

```
...
slider.append(
    $('<div class="slice slice'+id+'" style="position:absolute;"><img src="'+ $(imagen).attr('src') +'" style="position:absolute; width:'+ slider.width() +'px; height:'+slider.height()+'px; display:block !important; top:'+ j*-1 +'px;; left:'+ i * anchoSlide*-1 +'px;" /></div>').css({ 
        left:(anchoSlide*i)+'px',
        top:j+'px',                         
        width:anchoSlide+'px',
        height:altoSlide+'px',
        opacity:'0',
        overflow:'hidden'
    })
);  
...
```

Now you can add some CSS to all the `slice` classes and jQuery to a specific `slice3` class.

CSS:

```
slice {
    background: green:
}
```

JS:

```
$('.slice3').click(...);
```

Comment: yes actually I have it like that, it's using the class as if it was the name, it's just that later i want to apply a css to the class slice, so i just wanted for all divs the same class

Comment: Then why don't you give it two classes?  `class="slice slice3"`.  `slice` would be for the CSS that targets ALL slice divs and `slice3` for the divs with specific ids.  In any case, you should NOT use `name` on a divs.

Comment: yes that was the other solution i searched, and also i was gona apply it also, but i just thought "name" was a good solution, why isn't good naming divs?.. and also thanks for your answer and time

Comment: Because it is against the HTML specification.  While it may work now, there is NO guarantee this will work when Chrome 36 comes out.

Comment: You shouldn't use the `name` attribute on a `div` because the HTML5 spec does not allow that: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element. You can see that this page says the `Content attributes` allowed on a `div` are the `Global attributes`, of which `name` is not a part!

Comment: Thanks ajp15243... was just looking for that link. :)

Comment: oo well didn't knew that by bad, for best coding practice I'm not going to use it anymore, thanks for your answer

Comment: @DamianNuñez I would still keep Jeff's answer in mind, as that format can be used to select a specific value of any attribute in jQuery. You can read about all of jQuery's different selectors, including that one, here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/. Note there are different forms of this that use stuff like `*=` and `~=` that do different kinds of matching on the attribute value.

Comment: Worth noting that while Google has a major role in writing the HTML5 spec, and an even larger role in authoring Chrome, they themselves use Javascript that injects attributes into all sorts of tags that are not in the HTML5 spec, across a variety of their apps. It seems very unlikely this functionality is going to be removed, and if it is - someone should really tell Google.

Comment: @ajp15243 yes I was noticing that, with that format i can select anything thanks